# How do I silence PHP errors?

Tags: 7

Is there a way to silence all PHP errors, warnings and notices in Drupal?
They are usefull on the devel site but they are a big security risk, and make the site look bad on live.

I know on Drupal 6 the page at admin/settings/error-reporting can stop Drupal from writing errors to the screen, but where can I find this in Drupal 7? It seems it is missing.

Comment: Do note, though, that errors have a very important role: they indicate that something is wrong. Surpressing that, does not solve the underlying problem. This is also called the "Russian Method": When the alarm-light in a nuclear plant starts blinking, just remove the lightbulb. Alarm-light no longer blinks; no problems.

Comment: Funny :). But I only suppress error on the production site.

Comment: Drupal has the option to decide which errors should be displayed; not displayed errors are still recorded in the database, and shown in admin/reports/dblog.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, in production that is somewhat fine (yet presenting an error that a payment failed is always better then leaving your client in uncertainty). But in development and testing my experience is that errors pushed into dblog are neglegted. Drupalsites with hundreds of notices and warnings per hour logged there, is no exception. And real exceptions and errors are lost in the noise. Best is to push each and every notice hard into the face of the developer.

Comment: Right, but the OP seems to be interested to hide those errors in a production site. (See, "They are usefull on the devel site but they are a big security risk, and make the site look bad on live.")

Comment: Feature request here https://www.drupal.org/node/2743119

Comment: "I only suppress error on the production site" - that makes it worse!!!  At the very least, have the site send you an email when an error occurs. "Error: did not collect cash, but did send goods" - ignored 10,000 times :-)

Comment: and in drupal8?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The path changes, as in Drupal 7 the same page you would before see at admin/settings/error-reporting is now at admin/config/development/logging.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: For some reason, im not able to do this. On click of save my selection is getting reset. Is there a way I can change this manually in database or something like this??

Answer (score 20):

As suggested, in `Administration » Configuration » Development` (at `/admin/config/development/logging`) you can find the setting to disable **displaying** of error messages, but it won't disable error/notices completely.

It's because Drupal 7 enforces E_ALL, so they're still written to syslog and you can see them in *Recent logs* affecting your website performance.

To disable the notices completely, you'll have to add the following line into your `settings.php` or `php.ini` file:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

> Show all errors, except for notices and coding standards warnings.

To silence all PHP errors, which is not recommended, you may try to addin your settings file:

```
error_reporting(0); // Disable all errors.
```

See: [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/error-reporting)

---

Responsible Drupal 7 core code for `E_ALL` logging (file: `includes/bootstrap.inc`):

```
// Enforce E_ALL, but allow users to set levels not part of E_ALL.
error_reporting(E_ALL | error_reporting());
```

---

See also:

- [Enable users to determine which types of watchdog messages get written to syslog.](https://www.drupal.org/node/1408208) at DO
- [Add filtering to dblog before log entries go in.](https://www.drupal.org/node/1295182) at DO
- [Disabling PHP Deprecation Warnings and Notices](https://serverfault.com/questions/263167/disabling-php-deprecation-warnings-and-notices) at SF

Answer (score 4):

One thing no one has mentioned that may be helpful for people to know is that Drupal 7 ignores all local system error reporting levels. So you can't use .htaccess or even php.ini to set php error reporting levels in Drupal.

There is a patch proposed for this in D8, but currently in D7 you're restricted to the 3 error masks –all, none, or errors & warnings– that are set on the admin page kiamlaluno indicated.

Answer (score 3):

Settings are always in **admin/config/development/logging** :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I still want to have the green notifications alive. Hope they won't dissapear.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why the Drush method is so undocumented, but I have in my build script:

```
drush vset error_level 0
```

... which saves error messages to the log but doesn't show them on screen.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add quotes to the solution kenorb posted above:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', 'E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR');
```

Comment: This is wrong - those are constants, they should not be quoted. error_reporting is an integer value which is made up of the integer constants ORed together. It is not a string setting made up of constant names as you've got here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module for that:

https://www.drupal.org/project/errorlevelpermission

From the project page:

So you can

- have a sitebuilder role (or even a special debugger role) see errors and notices
- have others not see errors and notices.