# Can I suppress PHP error messages for authenticated users, BUT display all of them for an admin?

Tags: 7

I would like to suppress all the PHP error messages (errors, notices) for a regular authenticated user, BUT display ALL of them for an administrator (`$user->uid == 1` or user with an "*administrator*" role).

[This way](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/15417) I have the opportunity to set "*Error messages to display*" to "*None*" at `admin/config/development/logging`, but unfortunately this is a GLOBAL setting, which is not the right one for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested this but I would think you could turn that setting off completely, and enable it again yourself in a custom module:

```
function MYMODULE_init() {
  if (user_access('a permission only admins have')) {
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
  }
}
```

**Update**

Per your comments, it looks like this way doesn't work, but what *does* work is to do exactly the reverse of the above. That is, to set the error reporting to "All messages" in the UI, and then use `hook_init()` to surpress the unwanted levels of error message.

I would say your suspicions are correct, that Drupal is handling the errors at a lower level and so turning them off all together stops calling `error_reporting()` in `hook_init()` from having any effect.

Comment: oh, why didn't it come into my mind earlier, now it seems like trivial... :D Thanks, Clive! But maybe it would be better to check if a user has a specific role (e.g. `if (in_array('administrator', $user->roles))){...}`), wouldn't it? OK, I'll try that soon, and give you a feedback. Until then, +1 for your answer!

Comment: If you can get a solution working to your liking, I also think that hook_boot() may be a better place to do this.  I am not positive, though, if user_access() and siblings work here, though.  Using hook_boot() will allow you to detect problems in other hook_init()s.

Comment: @Sk8erPeter Whichever one you prefer really :) The normal 'Drupal' way to do it is to check by permission, so that your code is reusable (if you decide to grant that access to another role in future for example). Either way is fine though

Comment: @MPD Yeah I wan't too sure about user_access() in hook_boot() either so I just went with hook_init()

Comment: @Clive: OK,I tried that,and it doesn't work if I set _"Error messages to display"_ to _"None"_,and set a higher `error_reporting` level later in `hook_init()`,possibly because Drupal's error handler suppresses all these error messages. But it DOES work "backwards"! So I set the previous option at `admin/config/development/logging` to _"All messages"_, and after that, I checked if a user is NOT an administrator or does NOT have a right (e.g. `if(!in_array('administrator', $user->roles))`), and if NOT, then set error_reporting to a LOWER level (e.g. `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`, which takes out notices).

Comment: It did work this way (so leaving error display on _"All messages"_, and later suppressing error messages in `hook_init()` **if a user with _lower_ rights** is logged in). Could you please update your answer with these infos? Then I could accept it as an answer. :)

Comment: @Clive: so? don't you change the text of the answer? This way I can not accept it, because this way it didn't work, it just worked "backwards", as written before.

Comment: @Sk8erPeter Sorry I haven't really been on here today, I've updated the answer with what I think has worked for you :)

Comment: @Clive: BTW I think you're right when using `user_access()` function, one should implement [hook_permission()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7), define a given permission for viewing PHP error messages, and set `restrict access` array key to `TRUE`. If one has this permission, PHP error messages could be output.

Answer (score 0):

Use my [Error Level Permission](https://www.drupal.org/project/errorlevelpermission) module.