# Error entries in Watchdog duplicated dozen and hundreds of times

Tags: 7, performance, log-messages

I have seen that the table watchdog in my MySQL database is growing enormously, and after TRUNCATE, I see that for each visit to a single page, it generates hundreds of inserts, and when seeing them, they appear to repeat dozen and dozen of times. How can I trace where the error is, because I would bet this is a misconfiguration or something. I am worry that Drupal is making thousand of redirections, I have no other explanation, the pages load fast but the machine has a lot of RAM and hardware, so maybe I am loosing performance somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The best is to check what these entries are and try to fix them, e.g.:

- when the warning/error comes from contrib module, consider searching for this specific error and find out what's the solution (sometimes it may be misconfigured module),
- when warnings comes from your custom modules or themes, consider fixing it manually.

If you think you cannot fix the source of the issues, you should introduce caching mechanism to your site such as:

- Redis/Memcached which will limit enormous number of inserts into cache tables.
- Varnish to cache the front end pages.

or limit the entries by:

- limiting watchdog entries to warnings only (ignoring [PHP notices](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/184708/1908)) or [silence all of them](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/15415/1908).
- disabling `dblog` (database logging) module completely and switch to [syslog logging](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/syslog) instead.

See also: [How do you improve Drupal performance?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/24180/1908)